# Activity alias enabling with single top

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-activity-alias

In my app there is an activity with alias: `MyActivity` and `MyAliasActivity` registered in the Manifest. The purpose of the alias is to provide extra intent filter. This feature can be enabled/disabled in the runtime by the user. The activity and alias has got `singleTop` modifier.

However, if I start my app with the component disabled (`MyActivity` on the top), then I enable it, and broadcast the event matching the intent filter, `MyActivity` is created one more time (by the alias)- I've got two of them in the backstack which is undesired.

Can it he handled in any way? I need to have only one activity in the backstack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `singleTask` instead of `singleTop`. `singleTask` will guarantee that you only have one instance of an Activity in the backStack. In case you start an Activity for the second time with `singleTask` launchMode, the `onNewIntent` will be ran instead of creating a new Activity. Another solution is to use `singleInstance`, this works pretty much the same as `singleTask`, keeping only one instance of Activity and running `onNewIntent` if it is already created.

For more information here is a good explanation of how it works:

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en

Google reference:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Your solution works indeed, however, adding `singleTask` prevents the activity from handling onActivityResult correctly. As my project is a library that is attached to an activity I'm not sure if I can require the user to use `singleTask`. I thought that `singleTop` and `singleTask` works similarity if the activity is on the top. Apparently they don't...

Comment: You can also use `singleInstance`, might fit your requirements better and works similarly to singleTask

Comment: For further information, standard and singleTop work alike, and singleTask and singleInstance work alike

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider it.